# Is the Max RAM capacity limited per slot?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I was running the following command to find the maximum RAM an old mini-PC would take:
`wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices` and the results I got back were:

- MaxCapacity 32GB
- MemoryDevices 4

My doubt is that this motherboard has only 2 RAM slots (and not soldered RAM), so no idea why this is being reported as 4.

But, do those results mean that the mini-PC could take up to 32GB of RAM (2 x 16GB in my 2 real physical slots) or is that 4 in the results really significant and that means that each slot would just support 8GB (hence as I've just got 2 physical), it would mean 16GB total (2 x 8GB) and not the 32GB max as indicated by that command?

Comment: The command above reports the correct number of slots in my machines here. Do you have two other memory modules soldered onto the board as base memory?  That seems likely.  Memory per slot is normally a function of design and BIOS.

Comment: That command is only returning the maximum your system supports. Maximum memory module size is determined by motherboard then processor

Comment: Its often useful to jump on the Kingston or Crucial memory configuratir site as they often advise the memory layout as well as maximum size, number of slots and compatible memory.